# How to stop reading from stream on a disconnect gracefully?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have a simple socket connection that runs a read task in async. When I disconnect I get an exception:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'SslStream'.

I don't know how to stop it trying to read when it is sitting and waiting to read a message when I call disconnect. This is my read code:

```
    public async Task<int> Read(byte[] readBuffer)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        try
        {
            await Stream.ReadAsync(_header, 0, _header.Length);
            return  await Stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, _header[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e);
            Disconnect();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    protected async Task _RunReader()
    {
        var totalBytes = await Read(_readBuffer);
        if (totalBytes > 0)
        {
            HandleReader(_readBuffer, totalBytes);
            _RunReader();
        }
    }
```

And this is my disconnect code:

```
    public async Task Disconnect(bool graceful = false)
    {
        if (IsConnected && graceful)
        {
            lockPackets = true;
            Empty[0] = 1; // send disconnect message to server for graceful
            await Send(Empty,1);
        }
        Stream?.Close();
        TcpClient.Close();
        IsConnected = false;
    }
```

Is there any way to abandon `ReadAsync` when `Disconnect` is called to avoid getting an exception? It doesn't effect the program since I `try catch`, but I feel like there's probably a more elegant way than just allowing it throw silent exceptions?

Comment: I recommend you to catch only knowable exceptions, i.e. catch(ObjectDisposedException) instead of more general Exception type. As to question - this can happen. Network communication is the most unpredictable thing in application. It is async and unreliable without extra steps. In particular, this exception is "by design".

Comment: You got to finish or cancel the asynchronous call `ReadAsync()` **before** you close the stream. What you're doing is like changing wheels on a driving car. You got to do the things in the right order.

Comment: Hmm i see, not quite sure how to do that yet.

Comment: _"Is there any way to abandon ReadAsync when Disconnect is called"_ -- why do you want to do that? The code you posted shows a call to `Disconnect()` only when an exception has already occurred on the socket. Are you calling `Disconnect()` at some other time? If so, don't. "Graceful closure" implies that _both_ endpoints continue reading from the socket until a 0-byte read is returned. And of course you won't call `ReadAsync()` again if you get a 0-byte read, so problem solved. Your code has other potential issues, but focusing on one thing at a time: just keep calling `ReadAsync()` until done

Comment: All exceptions call disconnect and so do exceptions in other places such as my `Write` method.If that fails i call disconnect. And there in causes my Read method to obviously fail because its still waiting on the `ReadAsync` line

Comment: @Evk, I don't know for sure, but I have a horrible feeling that that version of ReadAsync will only process the cancellation token if there is anything to read. If the other end of the socket is not sending anything at the time this end posts the cancellation token, I don't think the cancellation happens. As I said, I may be wrong!

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding how to use it with the code examples Microsoft given for it.

Comment: @bazza well after some investigation, it's even worse - that overload is completely useless: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15033 (applies to full .NET also), so I deleted that comment above.

Comment: @Evk so is my only option simply to catch an exception and ignore it ?

Comment: @Evk, thanks for that. Eeeeeek! I had this nagging doubt having looked at doing something like this a long time ago and failing to make things work. I think the same problem applies to reading pipes as well. For the application I was writing cancellation was going to be problematic (even if it did work). The problem was, what was I supposed to do with the data from partially complete reads? I was facing having to push the read data into a queue and have the rest of the application read from that...

Comment: @WDUK yes I think so. When I now think about it - that's what I was doing all the time. You might want to catch `ObjectDisposedException` specifically (in addition to catching all exceptions), because you might want to handle it differently (for example, if you caught ObjectDisposedException - there might be no reason to log it or perform a `Disconnect` call). Here is also interesting read (but I don't think it worth using in this particular case): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/